# VS2010 DB Designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Trying to use Database Designer in VS2010 for the first time. I started adding Tables/ Columns to the Schema View and was able to successfully deploy the database to SQL server 2008 R2 on a server running windows 2008R2.

Then I discovered DB designer which seemed like a better & quicker way to create my database.  In server View I clicked on Database Diagrams and got this message

"The server does not have one or more of the database objects required to use database diagramming do you wish to create them"

So I clicked on yes but now my changes are not saved to the database and I am still asked this question every time I restart VS and click on Database Diagrams.    Also the project schema view does not match the designer view.

These errors have also appeared while trying to use DB designer.

“A Transport level error has occurred when sending request to server (Provider: TCP Provider Error: 0 An existing Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host”

Comment: Its seems I am having other problems in DB Designer as well. If I dont save the changes in the DB design for a undetermined period of time and then try to save changes the saving icon appears in the bottom right hand corner and VS become unresponsive and has to be killed in task manager. I wonder if the DB connection is being lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue with the SQL server instance installation/configuration.
If you have an option, and have not already installed it with VS, try to install an express version of the SQL to the local box (where the VS is running) and repeat the procedure.

The message for the database diagrams is ok.

My first response to this kind of message would be to check the firewall on the SQL2008 R2 box and SQL 2008 configuration.

Best regards, 
  M.

[SQL 2008 express download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff)

Comment: Installng SQl Express locally seems to have sorted out the connection problems thanks but any changes I still make in DB designer are stll not reflected in the project schema view.  

Am I incorrect in thinking that this should work like this?  Documentation on the designer seems sparse.